# Can I use “sein” plus past participle to express the passive voice?

Tags: passive, past-participle

In German we use *werden* plus a verb's past participle to express the passive voice. For example:

> Das Buch wird auf den Tisch gelegt.

Could I also say the following?

> Das Buch ist auf den Tisch gelegt.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, it is called "Zustandspassiv". "Vorgangspassiv" - with "werden" - leads to a result, which is in "Zustandspassiv".

> Der Hund wird gewaschen. -> Der Hund ist gewaschen.
>   Das Buch wird auf den Tisch gelegt. -> Das Buch ist auf den Tisch gelegt.

It sounds a little bit awkward in this example. One would say:

> Das Buch ist auf dem Tisch abgelegt.

Comment: +1 *[Es war getan fast eh gedacht.](http://wikis.zum.de/zum/Willkommen_und_Abschied)*

Answer (score -2):

No that's not possible.
correct options:

> Das Buch wird auf den Tisch gelegt. / The book is beeing put on the table.
>
> Das Buch wurde auf den Tisch gelegt. / The book was put on the table.
>
> Das Buch ist auf dem Tisch. / The book is on the table.
>
> Jemand hat das Buch auf den Tisch gelegt. / Somebody put the book on the table.
>
> Das Buch ist auf dem Tisch gelegen. / The book was on the table. (in this case, the verb "legen" changed its meaning from "to put" to "lying")

Comment: I'd weaken this, sometimes it's definitely possible, see [Veredomon's answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/18426/5437)